# GCE: how to find all disks attached to an instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I would like to find all disks attached to an instance.

When I do `gcloud compute disks list`, I get all of them. There's probably a `--filter` that can help, but I cannot find anything helpful about these filters in the doc.

Unless I make assumptions on the name of a disk to get the name of the instance (which I don't want to base any logic on), I'm still looking for how to get that.

Answer (score 6):

Should be easy with the format options as below.

`gcloud compute instances list --filter='name~test*' --project sampleproject --format="value(name,zone,disks[].deviceName)"`

Comment: THIS is the correct answer!

Just cos you can hack a string (that might change later) w/ sed or grep doesn't mean you should.  Filtering the source information is the right choice.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use the command below:

```
gcloud compute instances describe <instance-name> --zone=<your-zone> | sed -n -e '/disks/,/id:/ p'
```

Using piping you can filter you output, showing just the disks attached on your instance. Hope it can be useful

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @j-rojas but this one seems even better:

```
gcloud compute instances describe --zone=<zone-name> <instance-name> --format=json \
 | python -c 'import sys, json; print "\n".join(disk["source"] for disk in json.load(sys.stdin)["disks"])' \
 | xargs -I {} sh -c 'gcloud compute disks describe {} --format=json \
                      | python -c "import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)[\"name\"])"'
```

This way, it's cleaned up and ready to be piped in (one disk per line).

In one line:

```
gcloud compute instances describe --zone=<zone-name> <instance-name> --format=json | python -c 'import sys, json; print "\n".join(disk["source"] for disk in json.load(sys.stdin)["disks"])' | xargs -I {} sh -c 'gcloud compute disks describe {} --format=json | python -c "import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)[\"name\"])"'
```