# GCE : How do I list the all the disks and compute instances using them using gcloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I need to list down all the disks of a project along with the name of compute instances and some meta information like labels of those compute instances. I can write the gcloud command to list down the disks but not the compute instances. Any help here is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try running this command by @J.Rojas:

```
gcloud compute instances describe <instance-name> --zone=<your-zone> | sed -n -e '/disks/,/id:/ p'
```

You can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53497318/gce-how-to-find-all-disks-attached-to-an-instance) as well for reference.